# LinearLayout imageview + Text (left + right) differents layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

LinearLayout int LinearLayout imageview  + Icon (left + right)

I try to align to the right and I have many problems.

When aligned to left everything works fine, but when I try to right align the image is on the left side, because it is within a layout, and I do not know how to change layout.
is for a chat.

```
LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.text.getLayoutParams ();
LayoutParams lp2 = (LayoutParams) holder.text2.getLayoutParams ();
LayoutParams lp3 = (LayoutParams) holder.image.getLayoutParams ();
```

align  LEFT (WORKS)

```
lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
lp2.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
lp3.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
```

align  RIGTH (NOT WORKS)

```
lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
lp2.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
lp3.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
```

does not move from the left position:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:id="@+id/chat_layout1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/chat_layout2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/right_message_bg"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And how change image from other layout ? chat_layout2 ?

```
____
|   |  text  (work)
|___| 
____
|   |                    text   (not work right)
|___|
```

Comment: Would you make a drawing of the layout you want?

Comment: Try to define two layout with left and right side alignment and try to hide/show as per chat messages...

Comment: I tried, but not work, because I have 2 id Text, and only works with the first. 
checks and do them before changing position

Answer (score 0):

1. change xml width layout param of chat_layout2 to wrap_content.

   Your image layout is visible only because it's listed first. Your text view layout tries to be as big as it could. Also, image wrapping layout is redundant cause ImageView will still have LinearLayoutParam params.
2. and set gravity of (chat_layout1 & chat_layout2)'s parent (parent_chat_layout) to right - it'll change how its children are positioned. And also set it's orientation to horizontal.

Activity with Developer Options>Show layout bounds turn on:

[image: Activity with Developer Options>Show layout bounds turn on]

```
<LinearLayout ...>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent_chat_layout"
    ...
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView  
        android:id="@+id/image" ... />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" //IT SHOULD BE WRAP_CONTENT
        ...>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            .../>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            ..."/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent_chat_layout2"
    ...
    android:gravity="right"> //THIS SHOULD BE CHANGED, NOT CHILDREN'S GRAVITY

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1".../>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_layout21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" //THIS IS WHERE MAGIC HAPPENS
        ...>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
           .../>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text21"
            .../>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How I can put image left before text ?  ="  TEXT  [image]  "

Comment: In this case you need one more layout. Technically, you can get link ImageView to variable, than remove it from parentLayout (it was on 0 position), and than add it to parentLayout (it'll be on 1 position, while chat_layout will be on 0 position), but this is far more complex way than creating second layout.

Answer (score -1):

try using a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) instead of a LinearLayout. RelativeLayouts are much easier to work with...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link answers the question, provides relevant reading material and working examples, and it's from Google's Android Developers website so I doubt it will change anytime soon. That being said, I'll have no problem editing my answer and including an example after you cancel your vote-down.